# Como puedo hacer este diseno en tabla html

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Estoy intentando que el th me quede centrado mientras que abajo tenga tres celdas horizotal, me explico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi html que tengo por ahora:

```
<table id = "father">
            <tr>
                <th>Actual products in making.</th>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    hola
                </td>
                <td>
                    chao
                </td>
                
                <td>
                    hola   
                </td>
            </tr> </table>
```

le estoy dando colspan al th pero no se mueve, al igual que text-aling: center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tienes que utilizar colspan en el th  indicando cuantas columnas debe abarcar por ejemplo tienes 3 columnas abajo debes utilizar colspan="3"

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id = "father">
  <tr >
    <th colspan="3">Actual products in making.</th>
  </tr>   
  <tr>
    <td>
      hola
    </td>
    <td>
      chao
    </td>

    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel feugiat quam. 
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así a ver si te funciona, lo he testeado y va bien usando el `colspan`:

```html
<table id="father" width=100%>

  <caption style="text-align:center">Título de la Tabla</caption>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center" colspan=3>
      Actual products in making.
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td width=33%>
      Esto es un ejemplo situado a la IZQUIERDA
    </td>

    <td width=33%>
      Esto es un ejemplo situado en el CENTRO
    </td>

    <td>
      Esto es un ejemplo situado a la DERECHA
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```